# Show there is no prime in a range of numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

How do I show that except for 5039, there is no prime between 5033 and 5047. I just need a nudge in the right direction, no idea how to start the problem :(

Comment: That's a rather small range of numbers (just ~15 of them). Why don't you look for small factors of them, one number at a time? As a start, all even numbers in that list are divisible by 2. :)

Comment: Recall that a number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$.

If you write down each number between those two, that is $5034, 5035, \dots , 5046$ you'll notice that each one is either even, divisible by $3$ or divisible by $5$ except 5039.  That completes proof.

Comment: @EricNaslund How about 5041? It turns out to be $71^2$, but I know of no easy way to get that result. Of course, if you have a calculator handy, that changes everything.

Comment: @Arthur: Eric’s argument takes care of everything but $5041$. When it doesn’t succumb to the easy tests for $2,3,5$, and $11$, the fact that $50$ is just a little over $7^2$ and the number ends in $1$ could suggest trying $71^2$. Even if you think that you’ll have to test everything the hard way, you’ll want to know how far you need to go, so you’ll want $\sqrt{5041}$ anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It is also good to remember that $7! = 5040$. Hence, among the integers from $[7! - 7, 7!+7]$ the only ones that could be prime are $7! \pm 1$. But $7! + 1 = 5041 = 71^2$.

Hence, the only number that can be prime is $7!-1$.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$.

If you write down each number between those two, that is $5034, 5035, \dots , 5046$ you'll notice that each one is either even, divisible by $3$ or divisible by $5$ except 5039 and 5041.  Remembering our table of squares, $71^2=5041$, so that completes proof.

Comment: You didn't mention _divisible by 7_ BTW. 5033 and 5047 are both divisible by 7. =)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that a composite number will *always* be a product of primes, let's apply some tests and see the numbers that are factors of each. Note that I may not mention *all* the factors since one known factor can disprove everything.

Let's begin by scratching out even numbers from the list. Now, for the odd ones.

- $5033:7$
- $5 0 35: 5$
- $5037:3$
- $5041:71$
- $5043:3$
- $5045 : 5$
- $5047: 7$

So, the only prime number now is $5039$ which is good enough to complete the proof.